# Problem in peer-to-peer online connection

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am developing an Messenger application where i am trying to use an peer-to-peer online connection.

But for that i have to present my own user interface to configure the Internet connection.

how to do it?.. Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own UI for this, either programatically or with UI builder.

From: 
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKPeerPickerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/GKPeerPickerController

> **Important**: Although users can select
>   internet connections in the peer
>   picker, the GKPeerPickerController
>   does not provide an user interface to
>   configure them. If your application
>   configures the peer picker to allow
>   Internet connections, your application
>   must also dismiss the peer picker and
>   present its own interface to configure
>   an internet connection.